# What do you call two variables that if one of them is non-zero, the other is always 0 and vice-versa

Tags: notation

Let's say I have two variables x and y. 
*If x is non-zero, then y must be zero. Similarly, if y is non-zero, then x must be zero*

I'm writing a dissertation (in electronics) and I'm wondering if there's a technically correct way of saying the above perhaps using some neat mathematics?

Apologies if this is off-topic, I googled for it but couldn't find much.

Thanks.

Comment: One term that comes to mind is "_complement_". However, this is a very broad term. For example, in [Boolean algebra](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~cs561/cs330/boolean/Complement.html), if $x = 1$, then its complement is $y = 0$ and vice-versa. However, $x, y\in\lbrace 0, 1\rbrace$. That is, they cannot be _any_ non-zero values. On the other hand,  in [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)), a set is a complement of another if elements of the former do not exist in the latter.

Comment: Mutually exclusive? If one _is_, then the other _isn’t_?

Comment: How about, "whose product is zero".

Comment: Exectly one of them is zero? Exactly one of them is non-zero?

Comment: @kimchi That's also the case if both are zero.

Comment: It would still be correct because the reverse is not implied.  That is, $x$ is not necessarily non-zero even if $y$ is zero.

Comment: @AndrewChin this means the question is missing details. OP should elaborate.